# Difference between rect.move() and rect.move_ip in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was just going through the `.rect` method of pygame in the official docs. 
We have 2 cases ,

`pygame.rect.move(arg1,arg2)` which is used to move a `.rect` object on the screen
and

`pygame.rect.move_ip(arg1,arg2)` which is , according to the docs, also used to move a `.rect` object 
on the screen but it moves it **in place**

I didnt quite get what it means. Can anyone explain what **move in place** means?

Comment: One moves X and Y pixels from where it currently is. One moves it to a specific coordinate. IIRC:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"In place" means the object *self*.

While [`rect.move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) changes the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object itself, 
[`rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) does not change the object, but it returns a new object with the same size and "moved" position.
Note, the return value of `rect.move_ip` is `None`, but the return value of `rect.move` is a new `pygame.Rect` object.

`rect.move_ip(x, y)` does the same as `rect = rect.move(x, y)`

Comment: What are the advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, objects that appear to move are basically pictures that are shown very fast (24 pics per second or something like that) with a slight difference in the position . So at the core of the game , the `pygame.rect.move_ip(args)`  is ultimately a new image that is moved slightly from its original position . So what place is `.move_ip` more advantageous over the other?

Comment: *"rect.move_ip(args) is ultimately a new image"* is not a new image. We are talking about `pygame.Rect` objects. This are just rectangles with a position and a size. Non of this operations creates an image or surface.