# Ball doesn't bounce of screen edges in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I'm building a Pong game in Python with PyGame. For some reason, the ball in the game doesn't bounce off the walls / screen edges sometimes. It bounces off the walls once or twice and stops.

I don't know why that happens.

Could someone check my code to see if there are any errors?

```
import os
import pygame

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 500

class Slider:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = 120
        self.width = 8

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 64), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def move(self, dir, dis):
        if dir == 'top' and self.y >= 0:
            self.y -= dis
        elif dir == 'bottom' and self.y <= 379:
            self.y += dis 
        else: 
            self.y = self.y

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = 15

        self.speedY = 0.2
        self.speedX = 0.2

        self.top = y
        self.bottom = y + 30
        self.left = x
        self.right = x + 30

    def draw(self, win):
        ball = pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        self.top = ball.top
        self.bottom = ball.bottom
        self.left = ball.left
        self.right = ball.right

    def move(self):

        if self.top <= 0:
            self.speedY *= -1
        else:
            self.y += self.speedY
            self.x += self.speedX

        if self.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedY *= -1
        else:
            self.y += self.speedY
            self.x += self.speedX
            
        if self.left <= 0:
            self.speedX *= -1
        else:
            self.y += self.speedY
            self.x += self.speedX

        if self.right >= WIDTH:
            self.speedX *= -1
        else:
            self.y += self.speedY
            self.x += self.speedX


def draw_window(win, *sprites):
    pygame.display.update()
    win.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    for sprite in sprites:
        sprite.draw(win)

def main():
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong Game')

    slider1 = Slider(100, 250)
    slider2 = Slider(500, 250)
    ball = Ball(300, 250)

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                slider1.move('bottom', 0.3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                slider1.move('top', 0.3)
            else:
                print(pygame.key.name(event.key))

        ball.move()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            slider2.move('bottom', 0.3)
        elif key[pygame.K_w]:
            slider2.move('top', 0.3)

        draw_window(win, slider1, slider2, ball)


    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `move` method a bit, you need to remove the `else` blocks as they mess up ball's movement, just always move the ball once when calling `move`. You can also combine checking whether ball is on edge for an axis in one line (using `or`):

```py
def move(self):

    if self.top <= 0 or self.bottom >= HEIGHT:
        self.speedY *= -1

    if self.left <= 0 or self.right >= WIDTH:
        self.speedX *= -1

    self.y += self.speedY
    self.x += self.speedX
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked and Btw I had this code on before but the ```self.y += self.speedY``` and ```self.x += self.speedX``` was before the ```if``` statements. So it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Move the ball after changing the direction, in any case:

```py
class Ball:
   # [...]

   def move(self):

        if self.top <= 0 or self.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedY *= -1
        if self.left <= 0 or self.right >= WIDTH:
            self.speedX *= -1

        self.y += self.speedY
        self.x += self.speedX
```

---

Note, you do not need the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` attributes at all. Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = 15
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)  
        self.speedY = 0.2
        self.speedX = 0.2

    def draw(self, win):
         pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    def move(self):
        self.y += self.speedY
        self.x += self.speedX
        self.rect.center = round(self.x), round(self.y)

        if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedY *= -1
        if self.rect.left <= 0 or self.rect.right >= WIDTH:
            self.speedX *= -1
```

Answer (score 1):

What [Rabbid76 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413002/5730279) is pretty clever:

- to use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) as boundary for your *Ball*

You could either use composition (like below with a `self.boundary` component) or inherit Ball from `Rect`.

Then you can reuse methods from that *boundary* like [`move_ip(x,y)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip).
Or test inside of the screen by `screen.contains(boundary)` or some collision.

#### Non-integer movements

Even if the Balls position (x,y) might be non-integer (due to speed of e.g. `0.2`), the location on screen can only be represented as and rendered as integer pixel coordinates. Thus I deliberately use `round` and `pygame.Rect` for screen positions.

`pygame.Rect` represents objects in pixel granularity hence its attributes are stored as integers:

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers.

#### Test collision using a boundary of `pygame.Rect`

```py
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # use center to get (x,y) equivalent to former (self.x,self.y)
        self.center = (x,y)
        self.radius = 15
        # boundary as Rect (actually square) around the circle of the ball
        self.boundary = pygame.Rect(round(x)-self.radius, round(y)-self.radius, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)  
        self.speedY = 0.2
        self.speedX = 0.2

    def draw(self, win):
         pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 0), self.center, self.radius)

    def move(self):
        # move center to new position
        self.center[0] += self.speedX
        self.center[1] += self.speedY 
        # move boundary rectangle (screen position by integers only)
        self.boundary.move_ip(round(self.center[0]), round(self.center[1]))
        
        # test if inside the box using integers
        # if not pygame.Rect(0,0, WIDTH,HEIGHT).contains(self.boundary):
        if self.boundary.top <= 0 or self.boundary.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedY *= -1
        if self.boundary.left <= 0 or self.boundary.right >= WIDTH:
            self.speedX *= -1
```

See also this interesting post explaining the difference between `move_ip` (move in place) and `move` (which does not move the instance but returns the moved):
[Difference between rect.move() and rect.move_ip in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578694/difference-between-rect-move-and-rect-move-ip-in-pygame/61578756#61578756)